# MySQL, Altering Table from Latin-1 to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I would like to rid new entries into my database of Latin-1 characters and just allow UTF-8.  I plan to Alter table and make the following changes:

Charset: **latin1** -> **utf-8**

Collation: **latin1_swdish_ci** -> **utf8_general_ci**

The table in question has 1 million rows.  Is this a good idea?  What are the risks of doing this?  What happens to data that I try to input that is not in utf-8?  What happens to data that has been previously entered that is not utf-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a table duplicate, start a transaction, insert all the rows from the old table, and then commit. The safest way.

To summarize:

```
CREATE TABLE duplicate ... (with the charset you like, etc)

SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO duplicate (...field-list...)
   SELECT (...field-list...) from original_table;
COMMIT;

ALTER TABLE original RENAME TO original_backup;
ALTER TABLE duplicate RENAME TO original;
```

You must be careful with unique indexes and autoincrement fields. Be sure to create the duplicate table without indexes, to make the inserts quick, then add them.

Comment: Appreciate the answer santiagobasulto.  I'll do exactly as you suggested. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to ALTER the charset. The following 2 statements should convert you table and all columns.

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE schema.table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

If you have foreign key though be warned as you'll need to drop them, run the above SQL, then re-create them afterwards.